# All my resources require authentication after enabling authentication

Tags: authentication, dropwizard

I am working on an application using dropwizard, I am trying to set a simple use case where users needs to authenticate on certain resources (URLs) and not authentication on other resources.

After reading all tutorials, I am facing an issue where all my resources are getting forced to authenticate...which is not what I am looking for.

Here is what I am doing to start the application:

```
    environment.jersey().register(new AuthDynamicFeature(
            new BasicCredentialAuthFilter.Builder<User>()
            .setAuthenticator(new TestAuthenticators())
            .setAuthorizer(new TestAuthorizer())
            .setRealm("SUPER SECRET STUFF")
            .buildAuthFilter()
    ));
    environment.jersey().register(RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.class);

    environment.jersey().register(new AuthValueFactoryProvider.Binder<>(User.class));

    environment.jersey().register(new LoginResource());
```

My `TestAuthenticator` looks like:

```
public class TestAuthenticators implements Authenticator<BasicCredentials, User> {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestAuthenticators.class);

@Override
public Optional<User> authenticate(BasicCredentials basicCredentials) throws AuthenticationException {

    logger.error("Authenticator {}", basicCredentials.getUsername());

    if ("secret".equals(basicCredentials.getPassword())) {
        return Optional.of(new User(basicCredentials.getUsername(), basicCredentials.getPassword()));
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

}

My `TestAuthorizer` looks like:

```
public class TestAuthorizer implements Authorizer<User> {

@Override
public boolean authorize(User user, String s) {
    return true;
}
```

}

My `LoginResource` looks like:

```
@Path("/login")
public class LoginResource {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginResource.class);

@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response login(@Auth User principal, @Context HttpServletRequest request) {
    return Response.ok()
            .cookie(new NewCookie("test_cookie", request.getSession().getId(), "/", null, null, 5, false))
            .build();
}
}
```

Other resources are just normal resources, I tried `@PermitAll` on methods and it did not work, I tried at Class level and nothing.

I am using Dropwizard version 1.0.3

Thanks for any help.

Comment: PermitAll will ENABLE authentication. Can you post your other resource where this is not working?

Comment: You don't have to register RolesAllowedDynamicFeature if you don't have roles. Also, you can omit the registration of your Authorizer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Source - the dynamic feature will **ENABLE** authentication on @PermitAll, not disable it.

See this from AuthDynamicFeature:

```
final boolean annotationOnClass = (resourceInfo.getResourceClass().getAnnotation(RolesAllowed.class) != null) ||
            (resourceInfo.getResourceClass().getAnnotation(PermitAll.class) != null);
        final boolean annotationOnMethod = am.isAnnotationPresent(RolesAllowed.class) || am.isAnnotationPresent(DenyAll.class) ||
            am.isAnnotationPresent(PermitAll.class);

        if (annotationOnClass || annotationOnMethod) {
            context.register(authFilter);
```

So in order to not have auth on a specific resource, you can never apply it to class level (since it will then apply to all your resource methods).

See this example:

```
public class AuthenticatorTest extends io.dropwizard.Application<DBConfiguration> {
    @Override
    public void run(DBConfiguration configuration, Environment environment) throws Exception {
        environment.jersey().register(new MyHelloResource());
        UserAuth a = new UserAuth();
        environment.jersey().register(new AuthDynamicFeature(new BasicCredentialAuthFilter.Builder<Principal>()
                .setAuthenticator(a).setRealm("SUPER SECRET STUFF").buildAuthFilter()));

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new AuthenticatorTest().run("server", "/home/artur/dev/repo/sandbox/src/main/resources/config/test.yaml");
    }

    @Path("test")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public static class MyHelloResource {

        @GET
        @Path("asd")
        @PermitAll
        @UnitOfWork
        public String test(String x) {
            return "Hello";
        }


        @GET
        @Path("asd2")
        public String test2() {
            return "test2";
        }

    }

    public static class Person implements Principal {
        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return null;
        }

    }

    public static class UserAuth implements Authenticator<BasicCredentials, Principal> {
        @Override
        public Optional<Principal> authenticate(BasicCredentials credentials) throws AuthenticationException {
            return Optional.of(new Principal() {
                @Override
                public String getName() {
                    return "artur";
                }

            });
        }
    }

}
```

The MyHelloResource has 2 methods: `test` and `test2`. `test` applies `@PermitAll` to enable auth, while `test2` does nothing like that.

This means that auth is not registered to test2.

Here's the execution:

```
artur@pandaadb:~/dev/eclipse/eclipse_jee$ curl localhost:9085/api/test/asd -v
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 9085 (#0)
> GET /api/test/asd HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:9085
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Date: Tue, 01 Nov 2016 10:30:10 GMT
< WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="SUPER SECRET STUFF"
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Content-Length: 49
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
Credentials are required to access this resource.artur@pandaadb:~/dev/eclipse/eclipse_jee$ 
artur@pandaadb:~/dev/eclipse/eclipse_jee$ curl localhost:9085/api/test/asd2 -v
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 9085 (#0)
> GET /api/test/asd2 HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:9085
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Tue, 01 Nov 2016 10:30:14 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Content-Length: 5
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
test2
```

The first method denies access with a 401, while the second correctly prints test2.

Comment: That worked thank you for your answer, I guess I misunderstanded the permission annotation.

Comment: @Bambara no problem :) It is admittedly a bad name. It is easier to think of it as an Authorization annotation, not authentication. It defines what to do AFTER it is authenticated. also, if the answer is correct, you could accept it :)

Comment: Accepted the answer, that's exactly what I thought, the annotation would happen after authentication.

Comment: Yep - however to be able to do anything sensible with the annotation, authentication must happen first. Otherwise authorisation makes no sense since you don't have a user to authorise. All very confusing. I wrote my own version of that with an @Authenticate annotation the explicitly does nothing else but enable authentication, instead of having to rely on the (to me) confusing annotations provided

Comment: If you have a gist or github page for that, I am a taker. Thanks

Comment: Sadly i don't have that hosted, but you can base it on the same impl that DW has and simply have it look for your own authentication. Btw: Adding @auth as parameter into a resource method has the same effect and you do not need any other annotations to enable authentication

Answer (score -1):

Dropwizard prompts an API user to provide credentials for those methods that contain *@Auth User principal* parameter. If you remove the parameter and the annotation, the method will not be password protected.

Annotations like @PermitAll and @RolesAllowed have something to do with authorization, not authentication.

**Edit:** Take a look at [an example application](https://bitbucket.org/dnoranovich/dropwizard-getting-started).

Comment: This is NOT correct. See AuthDynamicFeature for details. PermitAll as well as RolesAllowed will trigger DW to register the authentication filter. So this will have the same effect as having the Auth annotation. The main purpose of the Auth annotation is to get the principal injected in the resource method. While Auth will ALSO enable authentication, if the principal is not required in the resource, you should use PermitAll instead. See docs: http://www.dropwizard.io/1.0.3/docs/manual/auth.html

Comment: But he returns true from his Authorizer, he doesn't have roles for users. He could not register his Authorizer as well. There are to ways to protect resources according to the docs http://www.dropwizard.io/1.0.3/docs/manual/auth.html. The older one is the one I described. Another one is necessary if you have role-based authorization. Although authorization requires knowing who is accessing a resource, so the filter is registered. The takeaway is that if your users don't have roles, one may use the @Auth annotation to protect desired resource methods. Your downwote is unreasonable.

Comment: First, this is a test code that I was playing with and that was not working, I was not at the stage of playing with permissions but what's the harm of doing a `return true;` if you don't have rules set yet :)  

On the other hand, what @pandaadb said is true, it's clear from the Dropwizard source code that `@PermitAll` will trigger an authentication, the `@Auth` is only needed to inject the Principal in the method you are trying to access, it serves for authentication also, but as we said in this thread, DW annotations are not clear and miss-leading.

Comment: Just offered you a simpler solution :). Nothing bad with true, you just can omit the registration of your Authorizer if you don't need it.